# Should the [discussion] tag be eliminated on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tag-block-request, meta-tags

Is there any reason to keep the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) tag on Stack Overflow, or should it be eliminated?

The [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/discussion/info) for [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) states:

> A discussion might be defined as the consideration of a question in
> open and usually informal debate.

This seems to directly conflict with the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask), which states (emphasis added):

> ### What kind of questions should I not ask here?
>
> You should **only** ask practical, **answerable** questions based on
> actual problems that you face. Chatty, **open-ended questions**
> diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the
> front page.
>
> ...
>
> If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to
> participate in a **discussion** about ______”, then **you should not be
> asking here**. However, if your motivation is “I would like others to
> explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK. (Discussions are of
> course welcome in our real time web chat.)
>
> To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed,
> avoid asking subjective questions where …
>
> - every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”
> - your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more
>   answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”
> - there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I
>   do.”
> - we are being asked an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if
>   ______ happened?”
> - it is a rant disguised as a question: “______ sucks, am I right?”

I had a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdiscussion%5D%20closed:0) and can't seem to find many questions that aren't open-ended. The questions that aren't open-ended tend to be mistagged or under-tagged, i.e. only tagged [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) when they [should have been tagged with more specific tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274543/png-images-positioning).

The majority of the questions tagged [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) can be classified as one or more of the following:

- off-topic
- not a real question
- not constructive
- exact duplicate (there are very many "How do you stay motivated?" and "How can I improve x?" questions)

Example questions tagged [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion):

> - [Are you taking up Perl and what got you into it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392789/)
> - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594473/
> - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016816/
> - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107078/
> - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807058/
> - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129601/

Does this tag belong on Stack Overflow? If so, what are some example questions that use this tag and which aren't candidates for closing due to one of the above reasons?

Comment: Huh, this might be a holdover from the days when meta questions were actually asked on Stack Overflow...

Comment: Let's discuss it.

Comment: @NickCraver I fully appreciated the irony while writing this :)